# Use Google Drive to create Google Blogger or Blogspot posts

Tags: google-drive, blogger

Is it possible to create and edit documents in Google Drive and then publish them to my Blogger account as posts? This is because the editor of Google Drive is far better for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the solution myself. Google used to have a feature **Publish to Blogs** under **Publish to the Web** on Google Docs/Drive and it had the option I was looking for. But sometime back Google dropped this feature very quietly and now there is no direct way.

Comment: You could still use the Drive editor to write the post, and copy-and-paste it into Blogger, though.

Comment: That would be awkard as image links etc would be lost

Comment: also "don't repeat yourself" principle